# Removing rows with digits and strings in pandas dataframe

Tags: string, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to remove the rows that only have digits or only characters in it. For example, below is the sample pandas dataframe column:

```
col1:

business
served business
02446681
C96305407PLA
P0116711
```

In my results, I would need the below values because the first & second rows contain only characters and third row is just digits.

```
col1:

C96305407PLA
P0116711
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using `pandas.Series.str.contains` with regex

Simpler regex but would allow for a row with `'123 456'` because both `'3 '` and `' 4'` satisfy the pattern.

```
df[df.col1.str.contains('\d\D|\D\d')]

           col1
3  C96305407PLA
4      P0116711
```

---

This addresses the shortcoming of the regex above by explicitly forcing the pattern to only match if either a digit/alpha or alpha/digit is found.

```
df[df.col1.str.contains('(?i)\d[a-z]|[a-z]\d')]

           col1
3  C96305407PLA
4      P0116711
```

Answer (score 4):

Using two `str.contains`

```
df[df.business.str.contains('\d+')&df.business.str.contains('[A-Za-z]')]
Out[48]: 
       business
2  C96305407PLA
3      P0116711
```

Answer (score 3):

str.extract and drop unnecessary rows.

```
df['col1'].str.extract('([A-Za-z]+\d+)', expand = False).dropna()

3    C96305407
4     P0116711
```